# jQuery cache JSON response based on endpoint

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to cache a JSON response in the case the endpoint fails or takes too much time to answer the request.

I have this function so far from a previous Stackoverflow question.
The problem is that this function returns always the previous request indipendently from the actual request. Since this function is used by more than one endpoints, I need not only to return the previous request in general ,but to return the previous request for the specific endpoint I am passing to the function:

```
var prevReq = $.Deferred().resolve().promise();

function getData(endpoint) {
    var newReq = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: endpoint,
        timeout: 2000
    }).then(function(data){
        // successful, set previous request to this request
        console.log(prevReq);
        prevReq = newReq;
        return data;
    },function(){
        // it failed, return the previous successful request
        return prevReq;
    });
    return newReq;
}
```

How can I edit this function to to the above?
Another problem is that it should timeout only after the first request, because if the endpoint does not respond correctly on the first request the object will always be empty and will never be filled with the data.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Just turn `prevReq` into a custom object so you can use it as a map to do something like this:

```
prevReq[endpoint] = newReq;
```

Comment: Ok cool, but it does not solve the problem of the timeout on the first request. I need to populate this data someway before

Comment: If you want to add a timeout only after the first request, you could do something like this (you need an initial value, here assuming null):
var opts = {type:"GET", url:endpoint};
if(prevReq[endpoint] != null) opts["timeout"] = 2000;
var newReq = $.ajax(opts) ...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses a `cacheData` object that will store only data , not promise, in form of `cacheData[endpoint]`

```
var cacheData={};
function getData(endpoint) {

  var defer=$.Deferred();
    var newReq = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: endpoint,
        timeout: 2000
    }).then(function(data){
       /* cache latest copy of data*/
       cacheData[endpoint]=data;
        defer.resolve(data)
    },function(xhr,e,txt){
        /* use cache if available, or pass another object if not*/
        var res= cacheData[endpoint] || {myError: 'No data available at at this time'}
        defer.resolve(res);
    });
    return defer;
}

function responseHandler(data){
   if(data.myError){
    /* do something when no data available*/
  }else{
    /* data available to use in your code */
  }
}

getData('data-1.json').then(responseHandler);
```

My demo has 4 cases...2 live files, one incorrect path ( to throw `myError`) and one bad path but has sample data in endpoint cache

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ybaESPhnm79H2o9sMfKT?p=info)**</kbd>